# Django Make user to superuser on the frontend

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to allow an admin/superuser to set already created users to be also a superuser. How would I go about this? I am new to Django.

There is a separate user editing page and I want to add a button that would by clicking it change the is_superuser to True.

Answer (score 0):

Then make the button that calls a view the does the change of is_superuser and is_staff and return a success message. This can be done by ajax using $.ajax

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to apply those changes to the django admin db.

Comment: Ger the user from db using objects.get and then change the values in obj and then save